# Assigning maxItems property in an array in JSON Schema equal to some other property

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a property called pageCount which is a number, followed by an array of information based on page number. Now, I want to set the maxItems in the array to be equal to the value of the pageCount. Is there a way that can be done? Most of the places I see we actually use a number to define the maxItems, but can we assign it a value of one of the property in the schema itself?

```
            "pageCount": {
                    "type":"number",
                    "mininum": 1,
                    "required":true
            },
            "pages": {
                    "type":"array",
                    "required":true,
                    "minItems": 1,
                    "maxItems" : <to be set as the the value of pageCount??>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of json-schema Draft v04 you can not use a "property value" to restrict minItems. According to the current state of the standard for minItems:

> The value of this keyword MUST be an integer. This integer MUST be
>   greater than, or equal to, 0.

If you have a small number of "minItems" different options, you could write a schema for each one, something like:

```
"minArrayItems" : {
    "type" : "array",
    "minItems" : 1
}
```

And then reference it through $ref:

```
"allOf" : { {
        "$ref" : "#/definitions/minArrayItems"
    }
}
```

This way you get an indirect way to modify values (just need to modify minArrayItems).

Another option is to add a pre-processing step and build the schema dinamically.

The best option depends on your actual context.